# Интерфейсы хотят дублирования реализованных методов и пропертей

Tags: c#, наследование

MSVS 2012, C#

```
class main : BaseClass, IMainInterface {}
```

Как доказать компилеру, что одноимённые методы и проперти из `BaseClass` и `IMainInterface` - это одно и то же и на них не нужно повторно ваять реализацию, что нужно ругаться только на новые методы, которые должны быть по `IMainInterface`, но которых нет в `BaseClass` ?

Примерно то, что я хочу, при том что я обязан наследоваться от `BaseClass` (чтобы не сломать совместимость с чужим кодом)

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void Print(string str);
    void SpecificIMethod();
}

class BaseClass
{
    public void Print(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}

class MyClassA : BaseClass, IMyInterface
{
    public void SpecificIMethod() {}
}

class MyClassB : BaseClass, IMyInterface
{
    public void SpecificIMethod() {}
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myClass = (IMyInterface)new MyClassA();
        myClass.Print("my message");
        myClass.SpecificIMethod();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: покажите код

Comment: И разве этот код не работает?

Comment: SpecificIMethod декларирует, а вот в BaseClass его нет, исправил

Comment: Вы не правильно ставите вопрос. Попробую уточнить. Вам необходимо расширить базовый класс? Если вы хотите передавать ваших наследников в те места где ждут IMyInterface то этот код полностью рабочий.

Answer (score 1):

Обновляю ответ. Вы пишете такой код:

```
    var myClass = (IMyInterface)new MyClassA();
    myClass.Print("my message");
    myClass.OtherPrint();
```

Тогда всё выглядит элементарно - если переменная **myClass** приводится к интерфейсу **IMyInterface**, то это значит, что вы имеете право вызывать у **myClass** только те методы, которые определены в **IMyInterface** - в общем-то очевидная вещь. В противном случае (если бы у интерфейса можно было вызывать не объявленные в нем методы) само понятие "интерфейс" было бы бессмысленно. В таком случае, вероятно, вам следует в вашем интерфейсе объявить метод **OtherPrint()**

Comment: Пытаюсь просто указать что BaseClass и отнаследованный от него MainClass имеют методы и свойства объявленные в интерфейсе. Линкуется. При выполнении ошибка
public class MainClass : BaseClass {}

var test = (Helper.IMainInterface)new MainClass();
// Unable to cast object of type 'MainClass' to type 'IMainInterface'.

Указываю что MainClass таки от базового класса И интерфейса
public class MainClass : BaseClass, IMainInterface{}
Даже не линкуется, на каждый метод и свойство матюки в духе
'MainClass' does not implement interface member 'Helper.IMainInterface.myField' C:\devel\test\MainClass.cs

Comment: @QuAzI что вам мешает показать код целиком? Зачем вы приводите какие-то обрывки? Покажите вашу иерархию наследования, покажите ваш интерфейс, покажите как вы их используете, как получаете ошибку. Пока что вашу проблему действитльно сложно понять, не имея представления о том, что вы пишете

Comment: а вообще ваша ошибка говорит о том, что вы не реализуете контракт интерфейса. Если в интерфейсе есть какие-то методы или свойства, то все они до единого должны присутствовать и в классе, реализующем интерфейс. В этом собственно и есть смысл интерфейсов - быть уверенным в том, что класс, реализующий этот интерфейс умеет делать то-то и то-то

Comment: DreamChild,
Я попробовал впилить интерфейс в уже работающий довольно крупный проект, само собой я не могу показать его исходники оригинальные

Comment: ну покажите сигнатуры методов, можете заменить названия методов на фейковые. В общем, смоделируйте ту же самую ситуацию на каких-нибудь тестовых классах и интерфейсах чтобы можно было точно судить о том, что за ошибка у вас. Скорее всего вы просто не реализовали в своем классе все свойства/методы интерфейса, поэтому при попытке кастовать экземпляр к интерфейсу вы получаете исключение в рантайме, а при попытке имплементить интерфейс в классе, получаете ошибку компиляции

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IMyInterface
    {
        void Print(string str);
        void OtherPrint(string str);
    }

class BaseClass
{
    public void Print(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}

class MyClass : BaseClass, IMyInterface
{
    public void OtherPrint(string str)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myClass = (IMyInterface)new MyClass();
        myClass.Print("my message");
        myClass.OtherPrint("second message");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: BaseClass писал не я, соответственно он не от интерфейса отнаследован, он просто напичкан данными методами.

Comment: >Если одноименные методы и проперти в BaseClass и IMainInterface это одно и тоже, то BaseClass должен реализовывать IMainInterface

в классе не может быть одноименных свойств и методов

Comment: Имеется в виду не свойства с именами методов, а наличие в BaseClass того же перечня свойств и методов что декларирует IMainInterface

Comment: Я вас еще раз прошу - приведите код., вы очень плохо объяснили, что именно вам нужно. Гадать на кофейной гуще - занятие не особо интересное. Однако наличие в классе-наследнике методов, имеющихся в предке и в реализуемом интерфейсе не должно быть проблемой. Компилятор на это ругаться не будет

Comment: На сколько верно я вас понял, то IMainInterface пишете именно то, то почему бы тогда не назвать методы и свойства интерфейса по другому, чтобы они отличались от BaseClass, тогда есть вариант унаследовать класс main и от BaseClass и от IMainInterface. Код приведу в ответе выше.

Comment: Если я назову методы и свойства по другому, я потеряю совместимость с родителем, а мне нужно именно маскировать потомков как единый класс, чтобы можно инициализировать разные классы выполняющие одну и ту же работу в зависимости от разных входных условий.

Comment: У вас по сигнатуре методы и свойства совпадают в BaseClass и в интерфейсе? Если да, то код выше прекрасно работает.

Comment: Добавил в шапку то, что примерно должно быть на основе вашего экземпла